# Как задать несколько классов в document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код на JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('allicon')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Можно ли задать в  getElementsByClassName несколько параметров, например

```
document.getElementsByClassName('allicon')[0],[1].style.display = 'none';
```

Если да, то как это сделать?

Подскажите как это сделать через `Document.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: или например с 0 по 5 ??

Comment: _Подскажите как это сделать через Document.querySelectorAll()_ - все то же самое: просто обходить возвращенную коллекцию в цикле и изменять нужные элементы